# Using a refresh token in AAD B2C with Azure App Service and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c, refresh-token

I'm trying to get a refresh token set up in my Xamarin.Forms app using AAD B2C. I've got everything set up but run into issues when calling `LoginAsync` on my `MobileServiceClient`. All of the [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/mobile-apps-easy-authentication-refresh-token-support/) and examples I can find show to update my `LoginAsync` method to this:

```
var user = await App.MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory,
    new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "response_type", "code id_token" } });
```

Except that the `MobileServiceClient` does not take a `Dictionary<string, string>` for the second parameter. It takes a `JObject`. Here's what my current code looks like:

```
var authResult = await App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(Constants.Scopes, "", UiOptions.SelectAccount, string.Empty, null, Constants.Authority, Constants.Policy);

var payload = new JObject();
payload["access_token"] = authResult.Token;

var user = await App.MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, payload);
```

I can not find an example use the `JObject` anywhere.
It is as simple as adding `payload["response_type"] = "code id_token";` to my payload?

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Mobile Apps support two authentication flows ([client-managed flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow) and [server-managed flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow)).

**Client-managed authentication**

> **Your app can independently contact the identity provider and then provide the returned token during login with your backend**. This client flow enables you to provide a single sign-on experience for users or to retrieve additional user data from the identity provider.

After you retrieved the token, then you would login with your azure mobile backend by passing the token into a `JObject` instance as follows:

```
JObject payload = new JObject();
payload["access_token"] = ar.AccessToken;
var user = await client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, payload);
```

For more details about other identity providers via client-flow authentication, you could refer to [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow).

**Server-managed authentication**

Your app directly contacts your mobile backend, then your azure mobile backend contacts the identity provider and provide you with the logged user.

- For Xamarin.Forms UWP app, you could login as follows:

[image]

- For Xamarin.Forms IOS app, you could login as follows:[image]

For more details about server-managed authentication in Xamarin.Forms, you could refer to [Add authentication to your Xamarin Forms app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users).

**UPDATE:**

I have checked that if you call `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync` in PCL, you could not see any extensions for `LoginAsync`. As you could see, there are many extension `LoginAsync` methods in the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll` for each platform. You need to define the `IAuthenticate` interface and implement it in each of your app (uwp, android, ios, etc.), for more details you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#add-authentication-to-the-portable-class-library).

Comment: Are those screenshots from a live project of yours? Because my version of Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client is `portable-win+net45+wp8+wpa81+monotouch+monoandroid\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll`, and that's the latest full release from NuGet. And it does not have the LoginAsync() with the Dictionary parameter.

Comment: And it looks like the only difference between server and client flow is that the client flow uses the token from the `AcquireTokenAsync()` method and passes it in the `payload` in the `LoginAsync()` method.

Comment: According to your comment, I assumed that you call the `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync` in your PCL. As you could see, there are many extension `LoginAsync` methods in the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll` for each platform. You need to define the `IAuthenticate` interface and implement it in each of your app (uwp, android, ios, etc.), for more details you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#add-authentication-to-the-portable-class-library).